# What is the difference between img and XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, cors

I am currently struggling with CORS. I want to request a picture which is generated upon request (e.g. a map from a WMS).

If the picture is loaded with the `img` tag the picture is displayed properly. But when I try to get the picture with a `XMLHttpRequest` it ends up with a:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?[...].
Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

You can find a simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJ67M/).

**What is the difference between these two methods?**

I want to use `XMLHttpRequest` because the requested picture is going to be a texture for a WebGL application.

Comment: And what do you plan on doing with the binary data of the image rather than referencing it by URL?  Are you actually looking for a CORS solution or are you just asking about the Same Origin Policy?

Comment: Actually x3dom uses it: http://x3dom.org/x3dom/example/x3dom_texture.xhtml

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" - the XHR attempt is failing / not using CORS. `img` is not subject to Same Origin Policy (or CORS).

Comment: SOP is there to prevent malicious code from being able to tamper with another site.  As HTML tags have very narrow defined uses which are not normally open to attack (unless your browser itself is somehow affected), they are not bound by the same restrictions.  In your particular case your best option is to keep the resources on the same site as the client code.

Comment: So I will first create a copy and then serve it to the client. Thanks!

Comment: Matt Whipples comment really should be an answer, as it answers this question perfectly.

Answer (score -4):

XMLHttpRequest is for loading data.

IMG is for loading images.

What's so hard to understand.

> [The XMLHttpRequest object is used to exchange data with a server
>   behind the scenes.](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)

As for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) states you have to have the server examine the  the Origin header from the client and include the origin as the Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: @mistapink My point was made before you commented with the link to the 3D demo. Apparently you want to manipulate the images via code and if you insist on loading images from other domains then the server dishing out the images will need to massage the header. I added a small edit to the answer

Comment: I know that I could change the servers headers, but I can't. Furthermore it doesn't answer my question where as @Matt Whipples comment does. (Btw: I didn't downvote)